# Linux framebuffer detect change

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, framebuffer, rfb-protocol

I would like to detect when framebuffer is chaning on linux framebuffer without `X`.

Where should I look into to find it? driver, kernel, a user space code? I know I can use `cp /dev/fb0 fb0` to copy the framebuffer and compare it to a previously copied framebuffer. But this is not efficient I think.

Comment: I have never tried it, but consider checking if `inotify` would be usable to watch `/dev/fb0` for changes.